# Solving non linear system containing a sum

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have several functions which comes from sympy.lambdify:

```
f_1 = sym.lambdify((z, m_1, m_2, s_1, s_2), expression_1, modules=['numpy', 'sympy'])
f_2 = sym.lambdify((z, m_1, m_2, s_1, s_2), expression_2, modules=['numpy', 'sympy'])
f_3 = sym.lambdify((z, m_1, m_2, s_1, s_2), expression_3, modules=['numpy', 'sympy'])
f_4 = sym.lambdify((z, m_1, m_2, s_1, s_2), expression_4, modules=['numpy', 'sympy'])
```

where `m_1`, `m_2`, `s_1`, `s_2` are scalars and `z` is a known 1D array (not necessary the same for each `f_i`). The output of each `f_i` is a scalar.

I would like to (numerically) find `m_1`, `m_2`, `s_1`, `s_2` so that,

```
sum(f_1(z_i, m_1, m_2, s_1, s_2)) = 0
sum(f_2(z_i, m_1, m_2, s_1, s_2)) = 0
sum(f_3(z_i, m_1, m_2, s_1, s_2)) = 0
sum(f_4(z_i, m_1, m_2, s_1, s_2)) = 0
```

The sum being on i.

Using scipy.optimize, I do not know how to implement it (using fsolve or root).

Answer (score 0):

To drive 4 functions F1, F2, F3, F4 all to 0,
minimize the sum of squares F1^2 + F2^2 + F3^2 + F4^2:
if the sum is small, each F must be small too.
(For example, sum < 0.000001 ⇒ each |F| < 0.001 .)
Use [scipy.optimize.least_squares](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#least-squares-minimization-least-squares)
to do this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
    # http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#least-squares-minimization-least-squares
    # http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html

# minimize F1**2 + F2**2 + F3**2 + F4**2 --
starting_guess = ...
ret = least_squares( [F1, F2, F3, F4], x0=starting_guess, max_nfev=20, verbose=2 )
xmin = ret.x
```

(Do NOT square the F s -- `least_squares` does that for you.)

In your case, you want to move the sum outside `lambdify`:

```
f1 = sym.lambdify((z, m1, m2, s1, s2) ... ))
Z1 = numpy array whose rows are all the z_i for f1

def F1( m1, m2, s1, s2 ):
    sum = np.sum([ f( z, m1, m2, s1, s2 ) for z in Z1 ])
    print "F1: %-10.3g at %-10.3g %-10.3g %-10.3g %-10.3g" % (sum, m1, m2, s1, s2)
    return sum

# check a few values in ipython --
F1( 0, 0, 0, 0 )
for x in np.eye( 4 ):
    F1( *x )
```

When that works, F2 F3 F4 are similar. Check them too. Then optimize:

```
starting_guess = ...
ret = least_squares( [F1, F2, F3, F4], x0=starting_guess, max_nfev=10, verbose=2 )
xmin = ret.x
```

or more iterations, or use `xtol` `ftol`.
`least_squares` has lots of options, see
the [full doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) .

There are fancier ways of doing the above for any number of functions, not just 4,
of any number of variables: more general, more obscure.

(Avuncular advice for optimization:

- start small
- check every step, with print statements, and interactively in ipython.